# Electron ignores loadURL() calls if opened with elevated privileges (uiAccess=true) by a non-Admin user

Tags: electron, uac, electron-packager, uipi

We have an EXE-packaged Electron application that needs to run under Windows with elevated privileges (uiAccess=true) to prevent user from accessing Windows when it runs in full screen.

Setting `uiAccess="true"` in the manifest file causes a problem: any `loadURL()` call is ignored silently, both for HTML files in local directory and to a locally running HTTP server.

- With `uiAccess` set to `false` calling `loadURL()` works well, for any user
- With `uiAccess` set to `true` calling `loadURL()` only works if the EXE is run by a user with admin privileges (even without running it "as administrator"), or if it is launched from a normal user account with "Run as Administrator" option.
- Otherwise `loadURL()` does not do anything, without throwing any error

Everything else seems to work normally (creating windows, capturing events, etc.)

UPD: I've added logging and found out that two events are emitted by `BrowserWindow`'s `webContent` shortly after calling `loadURL`:

```
"did-stop-loading"
"crashed"
```

This indicates that renderer process has crashed - but why? Setting `ELECTRON_ENABLE_STACK_DUMPING` and `ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING` environment variables to `true` does not give any more info.

Any ideas what could be a reason, and how can it be solved?